# Function composition in the IO monad

Tags: haskell, io, monads, function-composition, io-monad

The `lines` function in Haskell separates the lines of a string into a string list:

```
lines :: String -> [String]
```

The `readFile` function reads a file into a string:

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

Trying to compose these functions to get a list of lines in a file results in a type error:

```
Prelude> (lines . readFile) "quux.txt"
<interactive>:26:10: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: FilePath -> String
        Actual type: FilePath -> IO String
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘readFile’
      In the expression: lines . readFile
      In the expression: (lines . readFile) "quux.txt"
```

How can I do the monad trick here?

Comment: Composition is fine, but there's no shame in using a `do` block, like `do contents <- readFile "quux.txt" ; return (lines contents)`. Sure, using `fmap` or `<$>` would be more readable, but a `do` block is not that bad.

Comment: I use do notation, and then composition when I want to clean up my code *if* it improves clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't compose them, at least not with `(.)` alone. You can use `fmap` (or its operator version `<$>`), though:

```
lines <$> readFile "quux.txt"  -- Produces IO [String], not [String]
```

One way to express this in terms of a kind of composition is to first create a Kleisli arrow (a function of type `a -> m b` for some monad `m`) from `lines`:

```
-- return . lines itself has type Monad m => String -> m [String]
-- but for our use case we can restrict the type to the monad
-- we are actually interested in.
kleisliLines :: String -> IO [String]
kleisliLines = return . lines
```

Now you can use the Kleisli composition operator `>=>` to combine `readFile` (itself a Kleisli arrow) and `lines`:

```
import Control.Monad  -- where (>=>) is defined

-- (>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
-- Here, m ~ IO
--       a -> FilePath
--       b -> String
--       c -> [String]
(readFile >=> kleisliLines) "quux.txt"
```

Compare this with the `>>=` operator, which requires you to supply the file name to `readFile` before feeding the result to `return . lines`:

```
-- m >>= return . f === fmap f m === f <$> m
readFile "quux.txt" >>= kleisliLines
```

`>=>` is natural if you are already thinking of a pipeline in terms of `>=`; if you want something that preserves the order of `.`, use `<=<` (also defined in `Control.Monad`, as `(<=<) = flip (>=>)`; the operands are simply reversed).

```
(kleisliLines <=< readFile) "quux.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers given so far have been to make `lines` produce an empty monadic context, and then use monadic composition (`<=<`) to compose it with `readFile`. But you can also go the other direction: lift `lines` to operate through a monadic argument, and then use ordinary composition to combine it with `readFile`:

```
(fmap lines . readFile) "quux.txt"
```

Of course, if you're going to immediately apply this to an argument, it's simpler to just write

```
lines <$> readFile "quux.txt"
```